# open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) android phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I'm trying to use a Progress event with PhoneGap for file transfers.

My problem is that every time when I press the download button, the errors below appear.

I found the code under this link and copied it completely: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/05/01/Using-the-Progress-event-in-PhoneGap-file-transfers

Error: 
10-23 23:55:38.407  24464-24508/? E/FileTransfer﹕ {"target":"//download.mp3","http_status":200,"code":1,"source":"http://archive.org/download/Kansas_Joe_Memphis_Minnie-When_Levee_Breaks/Kansas_Joe_and_Memphis_Minnie-When_the_Levee_Breaks.mp3","exception":"/download.mp3: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)"}
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /download.mp3: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
            at org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openOutputStream(CordovaResourceApi.java:329)
            at org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openOutputStream(CordovaResourceApi.java:310)
            at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$4.run(FileTransfer.java:894)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
            at org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openOutputStream(CordovaResourceApi.java:329)
            at org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openOutputStream(CordovaResourceApi.java:310)
            at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$4.run(FileTransfer.java:894)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>FileTransfer Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
    <p>
        Kansas Joe McCoy and Memphis Minnie – "When The Levee Breaks"
    </p>

    <img src="img/KansasJoeAndMemphisMinnie.jpg">

    <p>
        <button id="startDl">Click to Download and Play</button>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="status"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceready, false);

var buttomDom;
var statusDom;
var fileSystem;

function deviceready() {
    console.log('dv ready');

    //step one is to request a file system  
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, 
        function(fs) {
            fileSystem = fs;

            buttonDom = document.querySelector('#startDl');
            buttonDom.addEventListener('touchend', startDl, false);
            buttonDom.removeAttribute("disabled");

            statusDom = document.querySelector('#status');
        }, function(e) {
            alert('failed to get fs');
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        });
}

function startDl() {
    buttonDom.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI("http://archive.org/download/Kansas_Joe_Memphis_Minnie-When_Levee_Breaks/Kansas_Joe_and_Memphis_Minnie-When_the_Levee_Breaks.mp3");

    var downloadPath = fileSystem.root.fullPath + "/download.mp3";

    ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
            var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
            statusDom.innerHTML = perc + "% loaded...";
        } else {
            if(statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
                statusDom.innerHTML = "Loading";
            } else {
                statusDom.innerHTML += ".";
            }
        }
    };

    ft.download(uri, downloadPath, 
    function(entry) {
        statusDom.innerHTML = "";
        var media = new Media(entry.fullPath, null, function(e) { alert(JSON.stringify(e));});
        media.play();

    }, 
    function(error) {
        alert('Crap something went wrong...');  
    });


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, I changed the fullpath to root.toURL() .